# Passing Object to function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, json, function, object, websocket

I am trying to send an object (JSON Array) to a xmlHttprequest in a function.  If I hard code the `body` variable inside the `getToteMatrix` function it works. But when I try to pass the `body` variable to the function from outside the function I get a 500 error.

- declaring the body variable inside the function :)
- calling the function and passing the body variable to the function. :(
- passing the body variable directly to the function :(

```
getToteMatrix(body);

var body = '{"Action":"<must be non blank>", "SubAction":"", "Cart":"", "CartPositions":1,"OverallTC":false, "ErrorMessage":"","UserResponse1":"","UserResponse2":"","UserResponse3":"","DisplayData":[{"Part":"", "PartDesc1":"", "PartDesc2":"", "UserField":"", "Location":"", "DirectionalDisplay":"", "TotalPickQty":"5", "StartingAisle":"","FullTote":"", "FullToteQty":"", "NewToteQty":""}    ],"BatchData":[{"RemainingPickLines":0, "RemainingLocs":0, "CurrentPicksPerHourRate":0.000}],"AlphaPos":[{"Pos": 1, "PrimaryModule":1, "SecondaryModule":3, "Message":"1111", "Color": 1, "BlinkSpeed": 0, "Buzzer": true, "Enable":true},{"Pos": 2, "PrimaryModule":2, "SecondaryModule":4, "Message":"2222", "Color": 1, "BlinkSpeed": 0, "Buzzer": false, "Enable":true}],"BatchPos": [{"Pos": 15, "PrimaryModule":1, "SecondaryModule":51, "Display":"*15*", "TC":false, "Color":1, "BlinkSpeed":0, "Enable":true, "Visible":true}, {"Pos": 2, "PrimaryModule":2, "SecondaryModule":52, "Display":"2222", "TC":false, "Color":1, "BlinkSpeed":0, "Enable":true, "Visible":true}, {"Pos": 5, "PrimaryModule":5, "SecondaryModule":55, "Display":"FIVE", "TC":false, "Color":1, "BlinkSpeed":0, "Enable":true, "Visible":true},{"Pos": 3, "PrimaryModule":3, "SecondaryModule":53, "Display":"3333", "TC":false, "Color":1, "BlinkSpeed":0, "Enable":true, "Visible":false},{"Pos": 4, "PrimaryModule":4, "SecondaryModule":54, "Display":"4444", "TC":false, "Color":1, "BlinkSpeed":0, "Enable":true, "Visible":true}]}';

function getToteMatrix(body) {
    // when the body variable is declared here the xml request works just fine.           
    // var body = (above json)

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://promat.dovetree.com/cart/cart/batchpos";

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send(body);
}
```

The function should take the data and output in a HTML format pushed from the server. I get a 500 error with the variable declared outside the function.

Comment: you're not showing how you call `getToteMatrix` - maybe you are, but you've screwed up the code formatting ... calling `getToteMatrix(body);` BEFORE declaring `var body` will mean you call `getToteMatrix` with `undefined` as the argument

Comment: As already mentioned you need to show more of your code so we have a better idea of what you're doing but based on how I'm interpreting things, it sounds like you might need a call to JSON.stringify to convert your object to JSON before passing it to getToteMatrix.  getToteMatrix(JSON.stringify(my_object))

Comment: @clockwatcher `body` is already a string in JSON format.

Comment: @Barmer -- his question states "if i hard code the body it works" that implies it works as a string.  But we don't have the code where he actually calls it to see what he is really passing.  I'm guessing that is the exact problem-- that when he actually calls his function he isn't passing a string but an object.  That's why I mentioned that we need to see more code.

Comment: First You need to write a function then you call the function.

Comment: put this getToteMatrix(body); at the end , you are using it the body variable before it has been declared so it will not get its value least you have a proper hoisting

Comment: @Barmer - someone edited his question after my initial comment post.  If the code is as it now posted then the problem is obvious.  But it's hard to believe that he wouldn't understand the problem if the code is actually as it's posted now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get a 500 error because, the time you call `getToteMatrix()` with the `body` as parameter, `body` is **undefined**.

Due to *hoisting*, javascript compiler, reads the variables like this:

```
getToteMatrix // function reference
anotherBody
body
```

**Function declarations precede variable declarations.**

Check the following example:

- The first time `getToteMatrix(body)` is called, `body` is undefined.
- The second time `getToteMatrix(anotherBody)` is called, we have declared `anotherBody` before that call, so it gets printed in the console.

```js
getToteMatrix(body);

var anotherBody = 'anotherBody';
getToteMatrix(anotherBody);

var body = 'text';
function getToteMatrix(body) {
    console.log(body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was definitely one of my issues. The second issue was Body was the parsed form of the JSON object. I should have been passing (evt.data) the raw JSON to the function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
function getToteMatrix(body) {
    console.log(body);
}
// first call
var body = 'text';
getToteMatrix(body);

// second call
var anotherBody = 'anotherBody';
getToteMatrix(anotherBody);
```

Here You need to call like this You Need to write a function First then call a Function Otherwise you will not able to get correct Answer.